# What do you call someone who makes decisions?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word that means someone makes choices. The choice doesn't have to be good or bad just that they are decisive. I am looking for the word to be in the form of a noun. As an example - "That woman makes many decisions; she is a **(insert here)**".

The only thing I can think of is chooser or decider but I'm not even sure those are words. 
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: ‘Decision maker’?

Comment: I had thought of that as well but I was hoping for a single word answer if possible. For example you can call someone who makes pies a pie maker but most people would just say 'baker'.

Comment: The second President Bush used [decider](http://www.cnn.com/2006/POLITICS/04/18/rumsfeld/). I'm not certain if that makes an argument for or against.

Comment: "Arbiter", "leader", or "director" are some suggestions.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch A 'decider' has a completely different meaning. If matches between two contestants are drawn (tied), and they play a further one to determine the winner, that game is known as a 'decider'.

Comment: @WS2 I've heard that usage in the UK; in the US it would be a "tie-breaker".

Comment: Someone who bakes bread is a baker. That doesn't make him a pie-maker.

Comment: @WS2 The English language would recoil in shame if it were restricted to such a parochial limitation to how it should be used.

Comment: @Jim Not quite as 'parochial' as you might imagine! Interestingly the only sport the OED mentions, for which it is used is horse-racing. But it is far more widely used in sport than that. But the following will indicate its origins: 1592   W. Wyrley True Vse Armorie 23   The Scriptures of God, the decider of all controuersies.
1764   S. Foote Patron i. 3   The paragon of poets, decider on merit, chief justice of taste.
1862   Bp. S. Wilberforce Let. in Life III. 106   The..danger of having..the Irish Bishops made the actual deciders of our doctrine.

Answer (score 7):

You can say decision-maker. Whilst this might look like 2 words, it's a single term, and because of the hyphenation, it's practically one word.

If you don't need it to be one word, you could reword the second bit to "she calls the shots".

Answer (score 0):

How about she is *the boss*, *the big cheese*, *the head honcho*.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think if she wasn't unwavering she could make many decisions  "that women makes many decisions,she is an **unwavering** person".
( by google's knowledge graph campaign which is said to be cause of downfall of Wikipedia's views but Wikipedia insists its a miscalculation -:

unwavering

(adjective)
1.
not wavering; steady or resolute.
"she fixed him with an unwavering stare".
synonyms: resolved, firm, steadfast, decided, unswerving, unfluctuating, unhesitating, unfaltering,untiring, unrelenting.

Comment: If you could provide the context in which she makes decisions , I could come up with a noun .eg-:an arbitrator is an official decision maker i.e an umpire , referee etc .I had researched on this topic just some time back for some question-:so I know the nouns and their context)

Comment: I think a person has to be resolute also in order to be able to make many decisions ( correctly )...of course the context here is not of any kind of mediation but for ourself.